# Error when loading the SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Today I installed the Android SDK for Eclipse. Everytime I start it, I get the following error:

```
Error when loading the SDK:

Error: Error parsing the sdk.
Failed to create C:\Program Files\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\add-ons.
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you dont have administrative Rights to set up your workspace/or other files?